# How to read import VRML (.wrl) into Mathematica

Tags: import, image3d

I wonder if there is a way to Import VRML objects, e.g. [here](http://alexei.nfshost.com/3d/virtual.html). The Export of These formats is provided but I did not found a way to Import it.
Can anyone help here?

(The Goal is to build a model of one of the insects from foam. Therefore I Need cross section of the 3D model.)

Comment: It doesn't seem as though VRML is listed under `$ImportFormats`, so it's certainly not officially supported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MMA dose not use the .wrl file format. You can use a free program called Blender.
This is the site to get your free copy of blender.
[Click here for Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/) Once it is finished installing, Import your file into Blender, and then Export the file to .3ds, And finally Import the .3ds file into Mathematica. Piece of cake

[image]

[image]